# Would you be so kind as to merge my accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts, users

My long-standing account is 29328/theory. One I somehow created without meaning to is 2372825/david-e-wheeler. Would you either delete the second one or merge it into the first?

Thanks!

Comment: We use this form for merges now: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge